# How much to heat mustard oil before cooking?

Tags: oil

We use mustard oil.

How do I know if the oil is ready for cooking?

My mother always waits till the pungent smell goes off. 
I can't put my finger to know if the oil is ready.

Comment: As far as I know, you actually *need* to heat mustard oil until it starts smoking, because this will break down some of the compounds which are deemed not fit for consumption (at least in EU, probably the same for the US). The ones here are always labeled "For external use only". But I gladly leave answering to better informed people.

Comment: Hello Mrstupid, health questions are off topic here. I had to remove the part about nutrients from your question. We could tell you if the oil is dangerous in the sense of "don't eat it underheated because you will end up in hospital with mustard poisoning" (that's food safety) but we can't discuss if less or more heated oil is "good for you" in some unclear health sense.

Comment: @rumtscho Thanks, but what about the **main** part: How do I know if the oil is ready for cooking?

Comment: The main part is fully OK, and I left it as you wrote it. Now we sit and hope that somebody who knows the answer will write it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if mustard oil is ready to use, add onion peel: if it browns immediately, the oil is ready to use.
You can also notice the change in fluidity of the oil.